# Error in transforming SRID in PostGIS 9.3

Tags: postgis

I am tying to use ST_Transform to shift SRID from 4326 to 25832. However, the resulting coordinates are far from the correct positions.

```
select x, y, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326), 25832))
from cmi.a_groenne_erhverv_temp;
```

produces

`55.6654496;12.5983956;"POINT(6158850.74362098 1998380.95066514)"`

The correct coordinates in SRID 25832 are 726304.755701 6174717.39191, which is nowhere close to the result of the transformation. If I leave out the `ST_Transform`, the result is

`55.6654496;12.5983956;"POINT(55.6654496 12.5983956)"`

Am I doing something wrong, or is it `ST_Transform` that fails?

Answer (score 4):

Judging from your name, I'm guessing you are from Denmark, or:

```
POINT(12.5983956 55.6654496)
```

And not from the Arabian Sea

```
POINT(55.6654496 12.5983956)
```

Your x and y are transposed.

Comment: You are right that I am Danish, and you are right that transposing the x and y coordinates produces the right result.
The standard for EPSG:4326 states the order of the coordinates should be lat, long, so I expected it to be so.
Thanks!